# Sencha Touch Select Field (selectfield) set default selected value without that value being in the store

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a Gender Store with the following data:

```
data: [
    {
        Value: 'Male',
        Display: 'Male',
        DisplayOrder: 1
    },
    {
        Value: 'Female',
        Display: 'Female',
        DisplayOrder: 2
    }
]
```

I would like to be able to have a Gender Select Field that has the default selected value/placeholder to be 'Select a gender' without having to add 'Select a gender' to the Gender Store as I don't want it to be a selectable value. I have tried using `value` and `placeholder` to no avail. Is there a simple way to do this?

```
{
    xtype: 'selectfield',
    label: 'Gender',
    name: 'Gender',
    displayField: 'Display',
    valueField: 'Value',
    store: 'GenderStore',
    value: 'Select a value', // no effect
    placeHolder: 'Select a value' // no effect
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer shortly after posting. Hopefully it is helpful to someone else:

```
{
    xtype: 'selectfield',
    label: 'Gender',
    name: 'Gender',
    displayField: 'Display',
    valueField: 'Value',
    store: 'GenderStore',
    autoSelect: false,
    placeHolder: 'Select a gender'
}
```